# How to change order of listed product in category section in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I have some products which have a category. All products belonging to category are listed in category section in magento as shown below-
[image]

Here all products are listed in DESCENDING order of their IDs. but I want to listed them in ASC order by 'Postion' column like below-

[image]

how can I do this.? Do I need a plugin for that or it could be done by changing in some files.

Comment: Change the position value to be as desired: id 107: 50, id 109: 40, id 105: 30, id 102: 20, id 95: 10 Then hit save category.

Comment: No it is not working again it is sorted in DESC order by ID.

Comment: Can you clarify? Is the issue that the order is correct in administration but incorrect in front end?

Comment: Fronend is working fine and getting in correct order but listing in backend is not correct.

Comment: First off try to reindex category flat tables: cd into root/shell and run php indexer.php --reindex catalog_category_flat Secondary turn on template hints by going to system->configuration->developer->template hints/blocks on to see which template renders your product listing then open that template file and var_dump the category products as they render to double check which order they come in as. If you still have problems, post the category listing file.